# Running two scripts and terminating one, when the other finishes

Tags: bash, shell

I have two scripts, one python and one c++. I need the python script to only run whilst the c++ script is active in the background, and then terminate at the same time. I have to do this as the python script contains an infinite loop which relies on the output of the C++ code. I'm a complete novice at this so I have written this bash script from answers I found here:

```
./test &
pid=$!

trap "kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null" EXIT

while kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null; do
        python display.py
done

trap - EXIT
```

but it fails to actually terminate the python script and it just keeps looping until I manually kill the process. I'm using ubuntu 18.04.1 if that's useful.

Comment: Why don't you use a pipe to connect both processes? The python one can read from the pipe to display whatever while the C process do its job. When the C finishes, the pipe is closed and the python one should also terminate. (BTW, the python one should not be an infinite look, but a process that reads from its input and terminates when there is no more input).

Comment: @Poshi This is the first i'd heard of pipes but you were right, i was able to remove the infinite loop from my python code and link the two processes with a pipe. Could you post this comment as an answer so i can mark this question as resolved?

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't really answered your question. I gave you a better approach to your problem, but the question at hand was resolved by the current answers. If someone else comes looking for an answer to the original question, better if he finds a working answer. There can be scenarios where you cannot solve the issue with a pipe, so better choose the answer you feel is clear or more useful from the current ones :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this part:

```
while kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null; do
    python display.py
done
```

Once the python display.py starts, the script stops and waits for it to finish. This means it is no longer executing the `kill -0` command.  You can start the display.py command if the other process starts, and then kill it when the C program finishes.

```
./test &
pid=$!

if kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null; then
  #c program started
  python display.py &
  python_pid=$!

  while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null; do
    #c program running
    sleep 1;
  done
  #c program finished
  kill $python_pid
fi
```

That being said, I agree with @Poshi. The better way to do this would be to use pipes. Since the python program is reading from the c program, you should do something like `./test.sh | python display.py`. The above answer is more of "how to hack the method you were already trying".

Comment: This worked! However you were right about @Poshi's suggestion so i ended up re-writing it using pipes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Bash, in common with other shells, has a built-in `wait` command to wait for background commands to exit.  Unless your top-level program needs to do other things while the other programs are running, you can simply run both of them in the background, wait for the first one to finish, and then kill the second one:

```
#! /bin/bash

./test &
testpid=$!

python display.py &
pythonpid=$!

wait "$testpid"

printf "Killing 'display.py' (PID %d)\\n" "$pythonpid" >&2
kill "$pythonpid"
```

If it would work to run the Python program before the C++ program then a simpler option is:

```
#! /bin/bash

python display.py &
pythonpid=$!

./test

printf "Killing 'display.py' (PID %d)\\n" "$pythonpid" >&2
kill "$pythonpid"
```